# invoking telnet from two different interfaces

Tags: telnet

I use telnet to test email server connectivity between servers.

My server has two interfaces, I'd like to telnet over each.

Basically I'd like to choose source (one of my local ip addresses) AND destination when using telnet.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 40):

My manpage tells me that `telnet -b <sourceaddress> <destination>` is the winning combination.

Comment: I wish I could do +2 for delightful use of manpage and slight sarcasm.

Comment: What os? I'm running rhel 4 and my man page doesn't have that option.  'telnet: invalid option -- b'

Comment: "slight"?  I must be losing my touch.

Comment: @foxhop: Linux NetKit version 0.17, released August 15, 1999.  I wonder if that's too new to have made it into RHEL 6...?

Comment: Now that is not slight sarcasm...so you still got the touch. Just had to warm up a bit I guess.

Comment: `telnet -s <source> <destination> [<port>]` on OSX

Answer (score 5):

I feel a little stupid for posting this as an answer, but I'm new so I can't reply to @RussellBallestrini

But you can try `telnet -s <src_addr> <destination>`

I'm doing this on OSX, not Red Hat—just thought I throw this out there.